# Edit Imagemagick policy.xml on laradock

Tags: image, pdf, imagemagick, policy, laradock

I tried to follow all guides on web to edit the Imagemagick policy.xml file using Laradock but I can't locate it.

I need to enable read&write for PDF as this:

```
<policy domain="module" rights="read|write" pattern="{PS,PDF,XPS}" />
```

Do you have any steps?

Comment: See https://imagemagick.org/script/resources.php

Comment: @fmw42 I know what I have to change, the issue is different. I can't locate the policy.xml file with laradock....

Comment: Can't you add that policy.xml by making a volume to that container?